# Project template for .Net Core Web Application missing in VS 2019

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I instaled Visual Studio 2019 and updated Visual studio to Version 16.4.5. I have 
 the component "Microsoft .NET Core SDK 3.1.101 (x64) from Visual Studio" installed in my PC. But when a try to create a web application in Core 3.1, I dont get the web templates. I have only the ones shown in the picture. I would appreciate some help on how to have the templates when creating a Core project [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project templates were available when I downloaded the 3.1 SDK from [link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1)